# How to update Nested Array with useReducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have these:

```
export type DataItemChild = {
  id: number;
  title:string;
  checked?: boolean;
};
```

Note that subItems can be undefined here:

```
export type DataItems = {
  id: number;
  title:string;
  subItems?: Array<DataItemChild>;
  checked?: boolean;
};

export const initalState: StateType = {
  items: [],
  date: new Date(),
};
```

So far I have figured out how to update the array on top level object like:

```
  case ActionKind.Checked:
    newArrayChecked = state.items.map((item) => ({
      ...item,
      checked: item.id === payload.id ? true : item.checked,
    }));
    return {
      ...state,
      items: newArrayChecked,
    };
```

I can not figure out how to update the subItems? i have this (stripped down)

```
export const reducer = (state: StateType, action: Action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  let newArrayChildCheck: Array<DataItemChild> = []
  switch (type) {

    case ActionKind.UnCheckedSub:
      newArrayChildCheck = state.items.map((item) => ({
        ...item.subItems?.map((sub, index) => ({
          checked:  sub.id === payload.subItems?[index].id ? true: sub.checked
        })),
      }));
      return {
        ...state,
        items.subItems: newArrayChildCheck,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

But this gives me a typscript error saying that my newArrayChildCheck does not support undefined. Full error:

> Type '{ [x: number]: { checked: boolean | undefined; }; length?:
> number | undefined; toString?: (() => string) | undefined;
> toLocaleString?: (() => string) | undefined; pop?: (() => { checked:
> boolean | undefined; } | undefined) | undefined; ... 29 more ...;
> [Symbol.unscopables]?: (() => { ...; }) | undefined; }[]' is not
> assignable to type 'DataItemChild[]'.   Type '{ [x: number]: {
> checked: boolean | undefined; }; length?: number | undefined;
> toString?: (() => string) | undefined; toLocaleString?: (() => string)
> | undefined; pop?: (() =

EDIT:

after @Kelvin Schoofs answer I realized I am sending in an entire object which has its subitems. the payload is of a type `DataItems`

I modified my attempt according to @Kelvin Schoofs suggestion with a little twist:

```
  newArrayChildCheck = state.items.map((item) => ({
    ...item,
    subItems: item.subItems?.map((sub, index) => ({
        ...sub,
        checked: sub.id === payload.subItems[index].id ? true : sub.checked
    })),
```

Not the `[index]`

But I am getting

> object is possible undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're spreading your new object wrong. Your `.map((item) => ...)` returns an object, but in it you spread a (potential) array, which would only fill in numeric (well, stringified versions) keys. You probably meant to copy over the original fields from `item` such as `id` and `title`, and assign the mapped `subItems` result to the `subItems` field. Idem for the object you create in your `subItems?.map`. Something like this is type-correct:

```
newArrayChildCheck = state.items.map((item) => ({
    ...item,
    subItems: item.subItems?.map((sub) => ({
        ...sub,
        checked: sub.id === payload.id ? true : sub.checked
    })),
}));
```

That's if you want an altered version of your `DataItems` array. If you actually want to return every `DataItemChild` with the `checked` version altered, you can use `flatMap` like this:

```
newArrayChildCheck = state.items.flatMap((item) => 
    item.subItems?.map((sub) => ({
        ...sub,
        checked: sub.id === payload.id ? true : sub.checked
    })),
);
```

Comment: hmm, you seem to be on to something here. I update the question a bit since I realized I am sending in an entire object so I need to check if the payload object has subitems and then find the subitem on state and update it: 

      newArrayChildCheck = state.items.map((item) => ({
        ...item,
        subItems: item.subItems?.map((sub, index) => ({
            ...sub,
            checked: sub.id === payload.subItems[index]?.id ? true : sub.checked
        })),

but cant get it to work.

Comment: I added an Edit on the question

Comment: I don't know what `payload.subItems` is, but apparently it can be `undefined`. Besides if you're indexing using `index` that's just a number, you'd have to make sure your `item.subItems` and `payload.subItems` have the same items in the same order.

Comment: Alright this made me realize that my structure is a bit off. Will accept answer since it gave me clearance. thanks!